# Event Sampling in Tesla GPU

Tags: cuda, tesla

I am trying to work with the CUPTI library in CUDA to read some performance counters like instructions executed, memory access etc. When executing the sample provided with CUPTI installation (/usr/local/cuda-5.0/extras/CUPTI/sample/event_sampling) it says '**Event sampling not supported for Tesla family devices**". (I am using a GTS 250). Does that mean I won't be able to read the counters during application execution or is it something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read the [cupti documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html).  The [event sampling API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html#r_event_api) is separate and distinct from the [metric API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html#r_metric_api).  The cupti metric API can be used to read counters associated with the metrics identified as supported on the particular compute capability you are running on.  For example, the supported cc 1.x counters are identified [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html#r_metric_reference_1x).

The error message you received indicates that the event sampling functionality (API) is not supported on devices of compute capability less than 2.0   `Tesla` as used here was an [NVIDIA codename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_200_Series) for a certain family of GPUs that predated the Fermi (cc 2.0/2.1) generation.

Comment: Is there any place where I can know what family of GPUs support capability  2.0 and above?

Comment: @Robert Crovella - I tried to use some capability 3.0 events like global_load_miss with the event sampling code of CUPTI. It gives me an error "CUPTI_ERROR_INVALID_EVENT_NAME for CUPTI API function 'cuptiEventGetIdFromName'". Why am I getting this error as K20 being  compute capability 3.5 device should support this event. I got this event from the table given at http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the event API with the metric API.  To find out what events are available for sampling on your device, use the `cuptiEnumEventDomains` [function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html#group__CUPTI__EVENT__API_1g3f6f5236a79cafda724796dc2d599ad1).  Perhaps you should post a new question if you're having trouble.